# Are tile overlays possible with the iPhone's MapKit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit, mkmapview, catiledlayer

I already have a tile source set up for use with the Google Maps JavaScript API.  I am trying to translate this for use with the iPhone MapKit.  I have correctly implemented the javascript zooming levels into mapkit.  Whenever `- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated` is called, I snap the region to the nearest zoom level based on the same center point.

Is it possible to implement a solution possibly with CATiledLayer to implement a tiling solution.  Does the iPhone use the standard 256x256 tiles like google maps does natively?  Any direction or help on this would be greatly appreciated.  I would rather not waste a couple weeks trying to implement this if it's not possible.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating further on how you ended up accomplishing this? I'm trying to do the same exact thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, since iOS 7, MKTileOverlay will do:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKTileOverlay_class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 12):

FWIW, I spent quite a bit of time looking for a decent solution… before diving into a CATiledLayer example, I noticed MKOverlay and MKOverlayView — which are new in iOS 4 and plug right into a MKMapView.

Couldn’t find a good example implementation of using MKOverlays that pull arbitrary image data (say, UIImages from a remote tile server), but I tinkered around with the API enough until I got it working.

Built a simple example implementation of it in case anyone (like me) wants a reference:

http://github.com/mtigas/iOS-MapLayerDemo

Hope this helps someone out in the future.

Answer (score 5):

MapKit doesn't provide much in the way of custom tile sources (in fact, it provides absolutely nothing to customize sources:  you either use Google Maps or you don't).  I've been working with a similar problem myself, though, and I've found RouteMe to be a pretty good solution for custom maps:  http://code.google.com/p/route-me/

Built-in support exists for OpenStreetMaps, OpenAerialMaps (which is currently offline), Virtual Earth, and Yahoo Maps, but the framework makes it pretty easy to plug in your own tile source, too.

Comment: I appreciate the answer.  I actually have a tiling solution now working based on MapKit.  My solution actually requires a mapping provider as I just have overlays.  If something happens, I will look into using route-me with Yahoo Maps.